# SQL Parallelism deadlock

Tags: sql, sql-server, parallel-processing

Until yesterday, we had been running SQL server 2016 with max degree of paralellism 1 (paralellism off) on our production sql. This prod sql is not a reporting sql or something like that. This sql is providing large number of operations for a website.

We have 16 virtual processors in 1 Numa node. (just one, not divided) so, we changed our prod sql maxdop from 1 to 16. And cost of paralellism is 50.

Since we changed this setting, we encounter paralellism deadlocks on the sql error log. One of them is like this;

---

```
2017-02-17 23:10:22.83 spid4s      PAGE: 6:1:12942122             CleanCnt:2     
Mode:IX Flags: 0x3
2017-02-17 23:10:22.83 spid4s       Grant List 1:
2017-02-17 23:10:22.83 spid4s         Owner:0x000000C8CBCF5840 Mode: IX            
Flg:0x40 Ref:0 Life:02000000 SPID:169 ECID:0 XactLockInfo: 0x000000C417DD64F8
2017-02-17 23:10:22.83 spid4s         SPID: 169 ECID: 0 Statement Type:     
UPDATE Line #: 1
2017-02-17 23:10:22.83 spid4s         Input Buf: Language Event: UPDATE op         
SET op.InvoiceDate = CAST(ud.InvoiceDate AS DATETIME)
FROM TROrderProduct op
    INNER JOIN AX_UpdateInvoiceDatesIds ud ON op.PKOrderProductId =     
ud.OrderProductID
WHERE ud.InvoiceDate BETWEEN GETDATE()-10and GETDATE()-1

--------------------    

2017-02-17 23:10:22.83 spid4s      PAGE: 6:1:14092111             CleanCnt:2             
Mode:X Flags: 0x3
2017-02-17 23:10:22.83 spid4s       Grant List 3:
2017-02-17 23:10:22.83 spid4s         Owner:0x000000CFBC765140 Mode: X            

Flg:0x40 Ref:0 Life:02000000 SPID:108 ECID:0 XactLockInfo: 0x000000CF14380440
2017-02-17 23:10:22.83 spid4s         SPID: 108 ECID: 0 Statement Type:     
ALTER INDEX Line #: 1
2017-02-17 23:10:22.83 spid4s         Input Buf: Language Event: 
DECLARE @return_value int

EXEC    @return_value = [dbo].[IndexOptimize]
        @Databases = N'CapuaDB', @UpdateStatistics = N'ALL', @LogToTable =     N'Y', @MaxDOP=1

SELECT  'Return Value' = @return_value
```

Do you think we shouldn't change this setting to 16 ? If so, what is the right value of this?  I researched about this subject very much and decided to do it 16 because we have 16 CPU in the same numa node. But we are encountering this deadlock issues everyday anyway.

Any idea would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: That's not a intraparallelism deadlock, that's a standard deadlock. Should you have changed it to 16? **absolutely not**! 16 cores for essentially SMP is also pretty high. If you want to use a higher maxdop, either look where it makes sense and use a query hint, use resource governor to do it for a set of actions, or set it to 2/4 and test. 16 which is the same as setting 0, is going to give you trouble.

Comment: Well setting threshold of maxdop to 50 is a good choice but you should really maxdop setting to `8`or `4` , trail and test see which one works best for you.

Comment: @SeanGallardy i might consider using this option with the value 4, then see what happens. If this deadlocks keeps happening, i will go back and set maxdop to 1. Thanks.

Comment: @M.Ali i didn't disable it. It was disabled and i changed it to 16 then seeing deadlock issues.

Comment: ... or you could not do index maintenance on the same tables you're updating all at the same time. (look at the deadlock)

Comment: @SeanGallardy i see what you are saying but this is just one of the deadlocks. Its happening normal daily operations as well. And generally happening in one query itself. Thats why i think its a parallel deadlock.